# How to get checked elements inside a object of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have A select field on my `UI` on change of which I am populating There respective data in a div which have `ul` and `li`, Now what I am trying to do is the `list` has check box `on`, `of` so whatever user selects and on button click I want to convert that into an object of arrays

**What I have done**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-search").hide();
  var Data = {
    "India A": [
      "Mumbai",
      "Delhi",
      "Kolkata"
    ],
    "India B": [
      "Bangalore",
      "Chennai"
    ]
  }
  var CountersName = Object.keys(Data)

  let dropdown = $("#counterNames")
  dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Select Counter</option>');
  for (var i = 0; i < CountersName.length; i++) {
    $('<option/>').val(CountersName[i]).html(CountersName[i]).appendTo('#counterNames');
  }
  $("#counterNames").on('change', function() {
    $(".card").show();
    $("#btn-search").show();
    var value = $(this).val();

    $(".card-header").text(value);
    // console.log(Data[value]);

    var ul = document.getElementById(".list-group");
    ul_innerhtml = "";
    for (i = 0; i < Data[value].length; i++) {
      title = Data[value][i];

      var ul_innerhtml = ul_innerhtml + '<li class="list-group-item">' + title + '<label class="switch "><input type="checkbox" class="success"><span class="slider round"> </span></label></li>';
    }
    $(".list-group").html(ul_innerhtml);

  })

});



$("button").click(function() {
  var selected = new Array(); // here I am trying to do


  $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).val());
  });

  console.log(selected)

});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: right;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  display: none;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input.success:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <label for="counterNames">Select Counter:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="counterNames">
    </select>

    <div class="card" style="margin: 10px 0; display: none;">

      <div class="card-header"></div>

      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">


      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-default commonButton" type="submit">
   <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Go
  </button>
</div>
```

When User clicks on go button  I want to retrieve which select option is selected and then which are checked on like this `{India A:["Mumbai","Delhi","Kolkata"]}` when `India A` is selected, I have tried to get it into array first but that shows up empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 mistakes in your code.

1. You have missed to add `value` to your checkbox;
2. You have missed to add name to your checkbox. but you used it while getting the value.
3. you have missed to get the selectbox value. which you want to define as a object and push your values in to it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-search").hide();
  var Data = {
    "India A": [
      "Mumbai",
      "Delhi",
      "Kolkata"
    ],
    "India B": [
      "Bangalore",
      "Chennai"
    ]
  }
  var CountersName = Object.keys(Data)

  let dropdown = $("#counterNames")
  dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Select Counter</option>');
  for (var i = 0; i < CountersName.length; i++) {
    $('<option/>').val(CountersName[i]).html(CountersName[i]).appendTo('#counterNames');
  }
  $("#counterNames").on('change', function() {
    $(".card").show();
    $("#btn-search").show();
    var value = $(this).val();

    $(".card-header").text(value);
    // console.log(Data[value]);

    var ul = document.getElementById(".list-group");
    ul_innerhtml = "";
    for (i = 0; i < Data[value].length; i++) {
      title = Data[value][i];

      var ul_innerhtml = ul_innerhtml + '<li class="list-group-item">' + title + '<label class="switch "><input name="type" type="checkbox" class="success" value="' + title + '"><span class="slider round"> </span></label></li>';
    }
    $(".list-group").html(ul_innerhtml);

  })

});



$("button").click(function() {
  var selected = {};
  var type = $("#counterNames").val();
  selected[type] = [];


  $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function() {
    selected[type].push($(this).val());
  });

  console.log(selected)

});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: right;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  display: none;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input.success:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <label for="counterNames">Select Counter:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="counterNames">
    </select>

    <div class="card" style="margin: 10px 0; display: none;">

      <div class="card-header"></div>

      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">


      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-default commonButton" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Go
 </button>
</div>
```

Comment: What are those mistakes?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry, added those mistakes now.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your logic is that your selector is looking for checkboxes with a `name` attribute, yet you don't add that when you append the `li` elements on change of the select.

Similarly, you need to add a `value` to the checkboxes, otherwise all their values will simply be the string `'on'`, which isn't much use.

```
var ul_innerhtml = ul_innerhtml + '...<input type="checkbox" class="success" name="type" value="' + title + '">...';
```

Finally note that you can use `map()` to create an array of values from a jQuery object, which saves the need for the explicit `each()` loop. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-search").hide();
  var Data = {
    "India A": [ "Mumbai", "Delhi", "Kolkata" ],
    "India B": [ "Bangalore", "Chennai" ]
  }
  var CountersName = Object.keys(Data)
  let dropdown = $("#counterNames")
  dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Select Counter</option>');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < CountersName.length; i++) {
    $('<option/>').val(CountersName[i]).html(CountersName[i]).appendTo('#counterNames');
  }
  
  $("#counterNames").on('change', function() {
    $(".card").show();
    $("#btn-search").show();
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".card-header").text(value);

    var ul_innerhtml = "";
    for (i = 0; i < Data[value].length; i++) {
      title = Data[value][i];
      ul_innerhtml = ul_innerhtml + '<li class="list-group-item">' + title + '<label class="switch "><input type="checkbox" class="success" name="type" value="' + title + '"><span class="slider round"> </span></label></li>';
    }
    $(".list-group").html(ul_innerhtml);
  })
});

$("button").click(function() {
  var selected = $(".success:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value.trim();
  }).get();
  console.log(selected)
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: right;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  display: none;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input.success:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <label for="counterNames">Select Counter:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="counterNames"></select>
    <div class="card" style="margin: 10px 0; display: none;">
      <div class="card-header"></div>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-default commonButton" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Go
  </button>
</div>
```